# No article for noun + number?

Tags: articles, definite-article, determiners, zero-article

I'd like to understand if there should always be no article before nouns followed by a number, like in the following examples:

- The train arrives **at platform** 5.
- The flight departs **from gate** 7.

In my native language, we don't have articles and it is unclear for me to understand why they are not used here. In the example about the train, we a talking about a particular platform at a particular train station. Is it always the case when I talking about some numbered nouns: page 5, house 7, platform 7, etc?

I did some research but I couldn't find explanations for my case. Here is what I found:

- ['Level' - no article? With an article?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142290/level-no-article-with-an-article). The sentence there was *I love playing games at easy level.* For that sentence, the answer was that "Easy level" is the name of the level and articles are not used before names. Is it the same case here?
- From ELU I found a very detail [Why no determiner before either 'lunatic' or 'knight' in “He's more lunatic than he is knight”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298758/why-no-determiner-before-either-lunatic-or-knight-in-hes-more-lunatic-than/298762#298762) answer but it didn't cover numbers. From it, I like the example *John is president of that corporation* with the explanation that the president is unique while *John is president of that corporation*. It may be similar to *platform 5*.
- There was [Noun + number and determiner (page 5, line 2, …)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256859/noun-number-and-determiner-page-5-line-2) question but there was no explanation for the reason in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is always the case with a noun identified by a number. We say _the first page_ but _page 2, the first gate on the left_ but _gate [number] 7_.

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339614/definite-article-with-numbered-nouns

Comment: The "why" question is hard to answer. The vast majority of native speakers could not tell you why; we simply learn that that's the way it is, and if, as children, we ask our parents why, they will either admit they don't know or make up a half-baked explanation. The link from Ronald Sole looks useful, though.

Comment: It's notable that with a lot of these we tend to use capitals ("Volume 2", "Chapter 3", "Episode 10", "Room 211", etc). But with "page 12", a capital is rare. So we should not conclude that the structure transforms the noun into a proper noun.

Comment: You should focus on understanding exactly what a ***determiner*** is. In your context, the numbers **5** and **7** are determiners, which is why we *don't* need to include an article (another determiner).

Comment: Thank you, your answers make it really clear! FumbleFingers' short answer especially makes it easy to catch the idea. I will post an answer with the summary because I found no way to convert comments into answers.

Answer (score 1):

Summary answer quoting comments from @fumblefingers, @ronald-sole and @kate-bunting.

> Yes, it is always the case with a noun identified by a number.

Concise explanation to understand the reason of that:

> You should focus on understanding exactly what a **determiner** is. In your context, the numbers **5** and **7** are determiners, which is why we don't need to include an article (another determiner).

Detailed answer can be found at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/339647/420906.

Other examples:

- weeks 31 and 32
- columns A and B
- team members Alice and Bob
- operations Charlie and Delta

Comment: In maths textbooks, I see all the time "One end of a string is fixed to _a point A_... the particle is held at the same horizontal level as _the point A_",  "The gradient of the tangent at _a point A_ on a curve is given by...", "Find the gradient of the curve at _the point A_ with coordinates (9, 9)" and so on.